# C# wpf datagrid, selecting one checkbox should select few others

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When a `CheckBox` is selected, few others also need to be selected based on the condition. Here I am trying to load the `DataGrid` with list of names, when I select one name, other names that start with same letter should be checked.
Please suggest me how to proceed with this.
How can I access the users list in Users class?

**Xaml code:**

```
namespace WpfApplication2  
{  
    public partial class MainWindow : Window  
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            List<User> users = new List<User>();  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe"});  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Sammy Doe" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Abhi" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Amy" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Arin" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Kate" });  
            users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Kane" });  
            dgUsers.ItemsSource = users;  
        }  
    }  

    public class User  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected;  
        public bool IsSelected  
        {  
            get  
            {    
               //I can implement my condition here, but how to access the users list?
                return this.isSelected;  
            }  
            set
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can not access the list of users. you can add a click such as:

```
 <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                          Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
```

xaml.cs code,

```
 private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            //checkBox.IsChecked

            //here you found checkbox IsChecked Property based on value you can write your code here.
        }
```

Note: If you want to notify it on UI than you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for updating UI.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Iam trying to implement similar event by using ICommand i.e when checkbox is selected, execute the ICommand and select other checkboxes depending on the command output.

Comment: Here is my datagrid:

Comment: <DataGrid x:Name="Commits" ItemsSource="{Binding ListofCommits}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommit}" 
           VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" /><DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Commit}" Header="ShowCommits" MinWidth="50" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

Comment: <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }"
                                          Command="{Binding CheckBox_Click}" />
                            </StackPanel>

Comment: CheckBox_Click is not triggered when I select the item, Is it possible to implement ICommand from the Datatemplate?

Comment: <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Command="{Binding YourViewModelCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>    Such  way you can bind command from viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ur isSelected property should be private.

Xaml

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Click="CheckBox_OnClick"
                                     />
```

MainWindow.cs

```
private void CheckBox_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        string name = (checkbox.DataContext as User).Name;
        var users = dgUsers.ItemsSource;
        foreach (var item in dgUsers.ItemsSource)
        {
            var test = item as User;
            test.IsSelected = true;
        }

        dgUsers.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

AS said above by Hima_devils if you don't want to Refresh ur whole dataGrid u can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your User class and inside ur setter u would

NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");

Comment: How to implement this in ViewModel, I tried to add to my model as

Comment: @bhavani Are you talking about the checkbox_onclick method or the INotifyPropertyChanged implementations?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to decouple your logic from the UI (i.e. your Window object). That means using [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) and moving your login in an object called [ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

In order to work correctly normally your viewmodels should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged). This interface represents an object which notifies if one among its properties changes its value. So you can use this mechanism for selecting the other users which belong to the list.

Let's see how.
First of all the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IWeakEventListener
{
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();
    private bool suspendListening;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        users.Add(CreateUser(1, "John Doe"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(2, "Jane Doe"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Sammy Doe"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Abhi"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Amy"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Arin"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Kate"));
        users.Add(CreateUser(3, "Kane"));
    }

    public IList<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return users;
        }
    }

    private User CreateUser(int id, string name)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Id = id;
        user.Name = name;

        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(user, this, String.Empty);

        return user;
    }

    bool IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (managerType == typeof(PropertyChangedEventManager))
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs = e as PropertyChangedEventArgs;
            User changedUser = sender as User;
            if (propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "IsSelected" && changedUser.IsSelected && !suspendListening)
            {
                try
                {
                    suspendListening = true;
                    foreach (User user in users)
                    {
                        if (user.Id == changedUser.Id)
                        {
                            user.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    suspendListening = false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

where `PropertyChangedBase` is a base class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Moreover I used [weak events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970850(v=vs.100).aspx) for checking when a user is selected.
As you can see if you select a user, all the other user with the same Id as automatically selected.
Your `User` class should derive from `PropertyChangedBase` too:

```
public class User : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool isSelected;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange<bool>(() => IsSelected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so your XAML will be:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Just remember to initialize the DataContext property of your Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```